# AVR gcc, weird array behaviour

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, avr

it's the first time I see something like this. I'm starting to suspect it's a hardware fault. 
whenever I try to send the contents of array "test" and that array is larger than 4 elements or I initialize all elements in the declaration it contains 0xff instead of values I try to initialise with.

this works fine. when I read values from the array in while(sending them to the lcd and uart) both readouts are consistent with test values:

```
uint8_t i=0;
uint8_t test[4] = {1,2,3,4};
     while(i<5){
     GLCD_WriteData(test[i]);
     USART_Transmit(test[i]);
     i++;
 }
```

this doesn't, it returns 0xff instead of test[i] value:

```
uint8_t i=0;
uint8_t test[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
     while(i<5){
     GLCD_WriteData(test[i]);
     USART_Transmit(test[i]);
     i++;
 }
```

but this works! it returns proper values

```
uint8_t i=0;
uint8_t test[6] = {1,2,3,4,5};
     while(i<5){
     GLCD_WriteData(test[i]);
     USART_Transmit(test[i]);
     i++;
 }
```

this also works:

```
uint8_t i=0;
uint8_t test[5];
test[0]=1;
test[1]=2;
test[2]=3;
test[3]=4;
test[4]=5;
     while(i<5){
     GLCD_WriteData(test[i]);
     USART_Transmit(test[i]);
     i++;
     }
```

it works fine when compiled on linux

I swapped out an mcu for a different one and it works the way it should. must be an hardware problem

Comment: This question is not particularly clear. Please don't just paste code and make us mentally diff it. *Explain* what the problem is. You say "returns 0xFF" - from where? That code is not shown anywhere. If your problem is in transmitting, why do we care about receive-side results? Isolate the problem. You're transmitting out a UART, right? Well then the obvious debugging step is to see what's *actually coming out* of the port.

Comment: You realize that, even though your array size changes, the bounds of your loop never changes, right? It's always `while(i<5)`. This is why an `ARRAY_LENGTH` macro is useful.

Comment: I edited my post to form it properly. the problem is, that when I initialize the array in the way I normaly do it array[]={1,2,3} and it's larger than 4 elements instead of my values it contains 0xff's. when I declare an 6 or more element array and initalize it skipping the last element it works fine.
I didn't change (i<5) values out of lazyness, it doesn't affect the problem. if the array has 4 elements it prints them out properly + one junk one, if it has 5 elements it prints 0xff five times, if it has 6 elements but 5 are initialized there are five proper values

Comment: I assume that in your first block, the `while` should be `while (i<4) {`?

Comment: probably some flow control problem with the port

Answer (score 1):

In first example you are going out of bounds of array test[4]. You are running while 5 times, when array has only 4 items length.

Comment: Although he said the first example works but the second example doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're overloading the USART. I assume that `GLCD_WriteData()` is VERY quick, and that `USART_Transmit()` buffers the character for transmission and then quickly returns. I don't know your hardware, so I can't tell - but a four-character buffer for a USART sounds reasonable.

Your five-character examples don't work because the actual character that you're trying to transmit is lost - so it puts an 0xFF in instead. You need to check the state of the USART buffer and wait for it to show that space is available (note **NOT** empty - that'd be inefficient!).

In the 8250 and 16450 UART chips there are two status bits:

- `TSRE` says that the **T**ransmit **S**hift **R**egister is **E**mpty;
- `THRE` says that the **T**ransmit **H**olding **R**egister is **E**mpty.

`THRE` can be set even when `TSRE` isn't - it's busy. I'd test `TSRE` and not send the next character until there's room - or set up a buffer and an interrupt handler.

Comment: the I/O hardware is not the problem, MCU checks the busy flag on the lcd and USART_transmit is just a single character hardware buffer and empty while that stops the program until buffer empty flag is set. I can make an array of 128 elements, assign values to them in a while loop and it will print them out fine. for some weird reason if I do 
array[5] = {1,2,3,4,5} and read it through a while loop it's all 0xFF.
also another thing, if I read it one by one: USART_Transmit(array[0]).. to 5 it's fine, but if I'll add a read by while to that code it suddenly becomes 0xff in both cases

Answer (score 0):

If it's not the I/O hardware, then the only other thing that I can think of is the compiler is producing incorrect code. What is the exact declaration of `USART_Transmit()`? Does it expect a `uint8_t`? Or something else, like an `int` (for some reason)?

If it's something else, like `int`, please try the following code:

```
while(i<5){
    int c = test[i];         // Whatever USART_Transmit wants
    GLCD_WriteData(test[i]);
    USART_Transmit(c);
    i++;
} // while
```

If that always works, then you've got a compiler problem, not a hardware problem.

**EDIT: Code for `USART_Transmit()` provided:**

> `void USART_Transmit( uint8_t data ) {`
>      `//Wait for empty transmit buffer`
>      `while( !( UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)) );`
>      `//Put data into buffer, sends the data`
>      `UDR0 = data;`
>      `}`

You've got something *better* than JTAG - you've got an LCD display! Although I don't know how many characters it has, or how long it takes to transmit a character...

You could try something like:

```
char Hex(uint8_t nibble) {
    return nibble<10 ?
           '0'+nibble :
           'A'+nibble-10;
} // Hex
...
void Send(uint8_t c) {
    uint8_t s;
    UDR0 = c; // Send character NOW: don't wait!
    do {
        s = UCSR0A; // Get current USART state
        //s = UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0); // Or this: isolate ready bit...
        GLCD_WriteData('x');
        GLCD_WriteData(Hex(s >> 4));  // Write state-hi hex
        GLCD_WriteData(Hex(s & 0xF)); // Write state-lo hex
    } while (!(s & (1<<UDRE0)));      // Until is actually ready
} // Send(c)
...
Send('A');
Send('B');
Send('C');
```

Assuming that UDRE0 is 3, then that code will result in a sequence like `x00x00x00x00x00x08x00x00x00x00x08x00x00x00x08` if it is working. If it produces `x08x08x08` then you've got a stuck UCSR0A bit, and it's hardware.

Comment: void  USART_Transmit(  uint8_t  data )
{
//Wait for empty transmit buffer
while( !( UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)) );
//Put data into buffer, sends the data
UDR0 = data;
}
your code has the same resault five 0xFF's.
I'm sure transmiting works, because if I replace test[i] with just 'i' even if it's an int I get the expected sequence 0-4. I wish I had a JTAG so I could take a peek in to the memory. I'm giving up on this one. I compiled it for other chip I had and it works fine. it will do for now. Thanks for trying to help! I'll just assume the problem is in the silocon

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but giving my feedback since this is the first place I got sent while searching solution for same issue, getting even exact same results with the code samples in original question.

For me it was a bad Makefile that caused some sections to be left out by avr-objcopy as far as I know.

For example in my case, the original parameters for building my sample hex that were causing this issue:

```
${OBJCOPY} -j .text -O ihex led.elf led.hex
```

What worked a bit better:

```
${OBJCOPY} -O ihex -R .eeprom led.elf led.hex
```